# Book recomendation: cell cycle regulation

Tags: book-recommendation

I aim to study cell cycle regulation, can some of you suggest a good book or website that systematically explains the topic.
It should include-

1. Detailed account of Cyclin and cdks involved in different stages of cell cycle
2. Spindle assembly checkpoint
3. DNA damage checkpoint
4. Special roles of Rb and p53 proteins in cell cycle regulation

Comment: A) [Useless title](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3393/this-is-the-title-of-the-meta-post-i-just-wrote), again. B) For book recommendations you need to specify with detail what the book should include detail on and why "obvious" choice are unsuitable - as it stands its far to broad/will illicit primarily opinion based answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robust texts covering such 4 listed points with rigour include the following selection:

- [Molecular Biology of the Cell](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK26869/)
- [Molecular Cell Biology](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21466/)
- [Cell Cycle Regulation](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Bc0REGcwLFEC&pg=PP1&lpg=PP1&dq=Cell%20Cycle%20Regulation%20(New%20Horizons%20in%20Therapeutics)&source=bl&ots=cHugqfn_oo&sig=C5GLZ35Na5bO-h2mxb8AOSqzErE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjz1_fqmIrNAhUJIsAKHVtsA7gQ6AEIMDAD#v=onepage&q=Cell%20Cycle%20Regulation%20(New%20Horizons%20in%20Therapeutics)&f=false)
- [The Cell Cycle Principles of Control](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/The_Cell_Cycle.html?id=ScEuiD2V6GoC).

& even a review of the latter [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/store/10.1002/bmb.90/asset/90_ftp.pdf;jsessionid=9B4D997D514F7CC1A4EE8F14D7A6377A.f04t03?v=1&t=ioyrin78&s=33acac369dcb11e48ba96f9638b35dc9e91e0bc6).

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Start with "Cell Biology" by Gerald Karp (Wiley). You can then move onto "Molecular Biology of the Cell" by Bruce Alberts and Alexander Johnson (Garland Science).